# How to get persian/arabic characters from url and then show it

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, farsi

I have coded this:

```
$url = "https://sitename.com/product-category/کتگوری";
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed['path'];
$path_parts = explode('/', $path);
$desired_output = $path_parts[2]; 
echo $desired_output;
```

Now the returned result is this: **`%d8%a2%d9%86`**

Which is referring to `کتگوری` but does not show up correctly.

So I need to show the `$desired_output` correctly in persian/arabic characters.

How to do this?

Comment: Can't reproduce https://onlinephp.io/c/eeb387 and though I don't speak persian/arabic, how could 4 bytes refer to 6 persian/arabic characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo rawurldecode($desired_output);
```